# Conditionally map a nullable field to None value in Slick

Tags: scala, group-by, slick

In Slick 2.1, I need to perform a query/`map` operation where I convert a nullable field to None if it contains a certain non-null value.  Not sure whether it matters or not, but in my case the column type in question is a mapped column type.  Here is a code snippet which tries to illustrate what I'm trying to do.  It won't compile, as the compiler doesn't like the `None`.

```
case class Record(field1: Int, field2: Int, field3: MyEnum)

sealed trait MyEnum
val MyValue: MyEnum = new MyEnum { }

// table is a TableQuery[Record]
table.map { r => (
  r.field1,
  r.field2,
  Case If (r.field3 === MyValue) Then MyValue Else None // compile error on 'None'
  )
}
```

The error is something like this:

```
type mismatch; found : None.type required: scala.slick.lifted.Column[MyEnum]
```

Actually, the reason I want to do this is that I want to perform a `groupBy` in which I count the number of records whose `field3` contains a given value.  I couldn't get the more complicated `groupBy` expression working, so I backed off to this simpler example which I still can't get working.  If there's a more direct way to show me the `groupBy` expression, that would be fine too. Thanks!

**Update**

I tried the code suggested by @cvogt but this produces a compile error.  Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in case anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong here.  Compile fails with "value ? is not a member of Int":

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver

object ExpMain extends App {

  val dbName = "mydb"
  val db = Database.forURL(s"jdbc:h2:mem:${dbName};DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver = "org.h2.Driver")
  val driver = H2Driver

  import driver.simple._

  class Exp(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Option[Int])](tag, "EXP") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def value = column[Option[Int]]("VALUE")
    def * = (id, value)
  }
  val exp = TableQuery[Exp]

  db withSession { implicit session =>
    exp.ddl.create

    exp += (1, (Some(1)))
    exp += (2, None)
    exp += (3, (Some(4)))

    exp.map { record =>
      Case If (record.value === 1) Then 1.? Else None  // this will NOT compile
      //Case If (record.value === 1) Then Some(1) Else None  // this will NOT compile
      //Case If (record.value === 1) Then 1 Else 0  // this will compile
    }.foreach {
      println
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to perform a query/map operation where I convert a nullable field to None if it contains a certain non-null value

Given the example data you have in the update, and pretending that `1` is the "certain" value you care about, I believe this is the output you expect:

```
None, None, Some(4)
```

(for rows with IDs 1, 2 and 3)

If I've understood the problem correctly, is this what you need...?

```
val q: Query[Column[Option[Int]], Option[Int], Seq] = exp.map { record => 
  Case If (record.value === 1) Then (None: Option[Int]) Else (record.value)
}
```

...which equates to:

```
select (case when ("VALUE" = 1) then null else "VALUE" end) from "EXP"
```

Comment: That's essentially correct (you mixed up the then/else clauses, but that's a minor detail).  I knew I was missing something simple, and boy was it simple.  So to summarize, in the "Then" clause, the compiler did not like for us to mix "value" (or "value.?") with "None", so the key insight is to mix "record.value" (already a Column[Option[Int]]) with "None".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap MyValue in an Option, so that both outcomes of the conditional are options. In Slick 2.1 you use the .? operator for that. In Slick 3.0 it will likely be Rep.Some(...).

Try

```
Case If (r.field3 === MyValue) Then MyValue.? Else None
```

or

```
Case If (r.field3 === MyValue) Then MyValue.? Else (None: Option[MyEnum])
```

Comment: I tried both of those, but they won't compile.  I get "value ? is not a member of MyEnum".  I tried simplifying the example further by using Option[Int] instead of Option[MyEnum], but I get the same compile error ("value ? is not a member of Int").  I've imported driver.simple._, so not sure what else is needed to get ".?" to work.

Comment: Right... you also need to tell Slick how to map MyEnum. See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries   Please keep me posted

Comment: yes I had already defined a mapped column type as described in my initial posting.  Also, have you seen my recent update?  I'm not able to get ".?" to work even with a simple Column[Int].  I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: The error messages would be helpful. Try upcasting to the correct option types, which is most likely the problem

Comment: Regarding the code shown in the update I provided, the compiler error message I get in my IDE is "value ? is not a member of Int".  Sorry, I'm not sure what I should be upcasting.  Care to comment on the code in the update?